# Video watermark

Tags: video, conversion

I am searching for a tool which can add text watermarks to my videos. I have a huge library (around 700 movies), ordered in folders. The video resultion of them vary from 360p to 1080p.

I am searching for a tool which can add watermarks to my videos, while:
1. it keeps the original folder structure
2. can handle diffrent video resolutions and makes watermarking easier

Thank you.

Comment: What program are you interested in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.org) is the program I would recommend, though the caveat is that you'll have to learn how to use the command line on your OS. The benefit of FFMPEG is its flexibilty: it can do a huge array of tasks, and being integrated into a command line chain you can use the power of the command line to deal with things like folder structures and different resolutions.